# Python tkMessageBox.askyesnocancel -- 3 options, boolean output?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkmessagebox

The documentation I have seen on `tkMessageBox` seems to indicate a boolean return for a user choice on an `askyesnocancel` dialog.  There are 3 options, so how can a boolean properly capture the user choice?

I've tried the approach shown below where a "yes" returns "True", "no" returns "False" and "cancel" returns "cancel", but that doesn't seem to work.  A "no" or "cancel" selection both seem to be returned as "False". Anybody have any ideas on this?

```python
if tkMessageBox.askyesnocancel("Error", "Choose yes, no or cancel", default='yes')
    ...
    ...
    ...

elif "cancel":
    return
else:
    pass
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, clicking `Cancel` returns `None`. Just test this with this line:

```
repr(tkMessageBox.askyesnocancel("wa", "wa"))
```

In conclusion, "Yes" yields `True`, "No" yields `False`, and "Cancel" yields `None`.

The problem you have there that both the boolean value of `None` is `False`, too. You have to explicitly check for `None`:

```
 if result is None:
     ...
```

Comment: Thanks!  I've added a new tool to my belt.

Comment: Actually, when I updated the code above with "elif None:" it still did not behave correctly.  It seemed to still handle any button other than "yes" as "False".

Comment: That can't work; you still have to do a comparison there, what do you think which boolean value `None` corresponds to? ;) So just assign the result of the messagebox to a variable and insert `if result is None` instead.